# How to print the variable user input in python 3?

Tags: python

So basically, I have a python program but there's a point in which I need help.
When the user input the variable name, I want it to print the variable value, not the variable name, even if the variable doesn't exist. This is what I've currently got:

```
    CMD = input(">>>>  ")

    if CMD[0:17] == "console.printVar(" and CMD[-1:] == ")" and CMD[-2:]!="')":
    try:
        CMD[13:-1]
    except NameError:
        print("Variable "+CMD[13:1]+" Not defined")
        Main()
    else:
        print(CMD[17:-1])
        Main()
```

Oh, and just in case it's not clear, i'm sort of working on a coding language sort of thing.

Comment: How does the expected input look like?

Comment: Why don't you store the "variables" in a dictionary, so you can easily access them by name (this is basically what Python does, under the hood)? E.g. `variables[CMD[13:-1]]`. You can use `variables.get(..., default)` or `... in variables` to deal with missing keys.

Comment: Oh, and if you're using recursion rather than iteration to keep your program looping, note that a long-running interaction will hit the [limit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just call `eval(CMD[17:-1])`.

However, this evaluates more than just variable names, so be careful that the user cannot do anything malicious with your code.

Comment: `eval()` is usually not the right solution in Python - there are dedicated ways to get to almost anything at runtime -, and this case (passing user inputs) is obviously the one where you _really_ _dont_ want to use `eval()`.

Comment: I agree that it's quick and dirty. Of course, there are better ways. However, depending on the context, quick and dirty might be good enough. Thus, my suggestion including a warning.

Comment: Thanks for you quick responses. This solved my problem . PEACE!

Comment: @AnthonyProvenza this will *work*, but be aware that it's a **bad solution** that will likely give you bigger problems later on.

Comment: What sort of problems can i expect later on?

Comment: @AnthonyProvenza see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761. Note that you need to add `@` to the start of names to notify the user you're commenting.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a global variable by name, use the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary:

```
name = CMD[17:-1]
print(globals()[name])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the local (function's) scope as a dict with `locals()` and the global (module's) scope as a dict with `globals()`. Now you may want to read a bit more about parsing, AST etc...